# How to convert XML attributes to text nodes

Tags: php, xml, json

I have a PHP script that pulls an XML file from a remote server, and converts it to JSON using simplexml_load_string and json_encode.  However, the simplexml_load_string seems to ignore inline attributes, like so:

```
<AxisFeedrate dataItemId="iid7" timestamp="2012-03-21T15:15:41-04:00" sequence="7" name="Yfrt" subType="ACTUAL" units="MILLIMETER/SECOND">UNAVAILABLE</AxisFeedrate>
```

In this case the JSON representation would be {AxisFeedrate: 'UNAVAILABLE'}

However, I need to have those attributes available.  One idea I've been approaching is replacing strings to turn the attributes into text nodes like so:

```
<AxisFeedrate>
  <dataItemId>iid7</dataItemId>
  <timestamp>2012-03-21T15:15:41-04:00</timestamp>
  <sequence>7</sequence>
  <name>Yfrt</name>
  <subType>ACTUAL</subType>
  <units>MILLIMETER/SECOND"</units>
  <value>UNAVAILABLE</value>
</AxisFeedrate>
```

I can turn the attributes into their own tag elements with regular find/replace, but I'm having trouble wrapping the original text value in a Value tag, at least with find/replace.

What are some good approaches for doing this?  The above chunk of XML is in the middle of many similar chunks on different data items, so I couldn't just start by replacing the first closing > with >...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SimpleXML itself to read the attributes.

Example:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_string('<AxisFeedrate dataItemId="iid7" timestamp="2012-03-21T15:15:41-04:00" sequence="7" name="Yfrt" subType="ACTUAL" units="MILLIMETER/SECOND">UNAVAILABLE</AxisFeedrate>');

foreach($xml->attributes() as $k=>$v) {
    echo $k." -> ".(string)$v."\n";

}
?>
```

---

Output:

```
dataItemId -> iid7
timestamp -> 2012-03-21T15:15:41-04:00
sequence -> 7
name -> Yfrt
subType -> ACTUAL
units -> MILLIMETER/SECOND
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `([\w]*?)="(.*?)"` with this replace `<$1>$2</$1>\n`

Comment: Won't that result in XML that isn't well-formed? Like `<AxisFeedrate <dataItemId>iid7</dataItemId>>`??

Answer (score 0):

You should use SimpleXML.  Be aware though, that you have to cast values to string type explicitly, or you'll get objects.

```
$xml_string = <<<XML
<AxisFeedrate 
dataItemId="iid7" 
timestamp="2012-03-21T15:15:41-04:00" 
sequence="7" 
name="Yfrt" 
subType="ACTUAL" 
units="MILLIMETER/SECOND"
>UNAVAILABLE</AxisFeedrate>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

$axis_info = array('value' => (string)$xml);

foreach($xml -> attributes() as $attr => $val) {
    $axis_info[$attr] = (string) $val;
}

echo json_encode(array("AxisFeedrate" => $axis_info));
```

### Update:

This will give you a more generic version, but notice that the attributes are cast as an array and that this only works on a single element:

```
$xml_string = <<<XML
<AxisFeedrate dataItemId="iid7" timestamp="2012-03-21T15:15:41-04:00" sequence="7" name="Yfrt" subType="ACTUAL" units="MILLIMETER/SECOND">UNAVAILABLE</AxisFeedrate>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

$obj_name = $xml -> getName();

$attributes = (array) $xml->attributes();

$axis_info[$obj_name] = $attributes["@attributes"];
$axis_info[$obj_name]['value'] = (string) $xml;

echo json_encode($axis_info);
```